The system cannot find the specified path (Qt creator 13.0.1 with msvc_compiler 2019) version Qt 6.7.1
The system cannot find the path specified.
jom: C:\\Project\\Config\\build-Desktop_Qt_6_7_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Release\\Makefile.Release \[release\\RPA_Config.exe\] Error 1
jom: C:\\Project\\Config\\build-Desktop_Qt_6_7_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Release\\Makefile \[release\] Error 2
12:54:11: The process "C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom\\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project RPA_Config (kit: Desktop Qt 6.7.1 MSVC2019 64bit)

When executing step "Make"

How to resolved this error?
